# How to travel a multiple branches tree and collect data in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I need convert json to another format, so I use instaparse to convert json to vector list.

original json:

```json
[
  {
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": {
      "k21": "v21",
      "k22": "v22"
    }
  },
  {
    "k4": "v4",
    "k5": "v5",
    "k6": "v6"
  }
]
```

convert to clojure vector list:

```clj
[:JSON
 [:ARRAY
  [:OBJECT
   [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k1\""] [:STRING "\"v1\""]]
   [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR
    [:STRING "\"k2\""]
    [:OBJECT
     [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k21\""] [:STRING "\"v21\""]]
     [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k22\""] [:STRING "\"v22\""]]]]]
  [:OBJECT
   [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k4\""] [:STRING "\"v4\""]]
   [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k5\""] [:STRING "\"v5\""]]
   [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k6\""] [:STRING "\"v6\""]]]]]
```

which visualize the tree in this link: [visualizing tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7dB6.png)

and I want to this format:

```js
[
  {
    k1: "k1",
    k2: {
      k21: "k2.k21",
      k22: "k2.k22"
    }
  },
  {
    k4: "k4",
    k5: "k5",
    k6: "k6"
  }
]
```

so how to travel a multiple branches tree and collect data in Clojure? I find it hardly use tree-seq and walk function, so I try to write the code:

```clj
(ns clojure.examples.hello
    (:gen-class))
    
(def json-tree [:JSON [:ARRAY [:OBJECT [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k1\""] [:STRING "\"v1\""]] [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k2\""] [:OBJECT [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k21\""] [:STRING "\"v21\""]] [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k22\""] [:STRING "\"v22\""]]]]] [:OBJECT [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k4\""] [:STRING "\"v4\""]] [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k5\""] [:STRING "\"v5\""]] [:KEY_VALUE_PAIR [:STRING "\"k6\""] [:STRING "\"v6\""]]]]])

(defn transform-key [x]
    (-> x
        (clojure.string/replace "\"" "")
        (clojure.string/upper-case)))

(defn transform-value [x]
    (if (= x "") x (str x ".")))

(defn bf3 "return elements in tree, breath-first"
    [[el & children :as tree] path] ;; a tree is a seq of one element,
                     ;; followed by left and right child trees
    (if (nil? el)
        (do)
        (if (= el :JSON)
            (do (print (get (vec children) 0))
                (bf3 (get (vec children) 0) path))
                (if (= el :ARRAY)
                    (let [[first & rest-list] (get (vec children) 0)
                            rest (vec rest-list)]
                        (do (print "[") (bf3 first path) (bf3 rest path) (print "], ")))
                    (if (= el :OBJECT)
                        (let [[_ [_ key] & rest-list] (get (vec children) 0)
                            [rest] (vec rest-list)]
                            (do (print "{") 
                                (print (str (transform-key key) ": "))
                                (print (str "rest====>" rest))
                                (bf3 rest (transform-key key))
                                (print "}, ")))
                        (if (= el :KEY_VALUE_PAIR)
                            (do (print (str (transform-key (get first 1)) ": ")) 
                                (bf3 rest (str (transform-value path) (transform-key (get first 1)))))
                            (print (str "\"" path "\", "))))))))

(bf3 json-tree "")
```

but it seems like this code only can travel one branch, the rest branches cannot travel.

Comment: What output do you expoect from `(bf3 json-tree "")`? And what is the reason for not using an existing json library such as Cheshire (https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire)?

Comment: To convert the source JSON directly to what is described as the target format, a better tool than Instaparse is Specter: https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely look into using [clojure.walk](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/walk)